# html tab splitting for python flask

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I have following code:

content.py

```
    import fnmatch
import os
matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("Z:\\"):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.iso'):
        matches.append(os.path.join(filename))

new_list = matches

result_string = """<HTML>
<body>
    <h1>ISO LIST</h1>
    <table>\n"""
for i in new_list:
    result_string += "        <tr>\n            "
    for j in i:
        result_string += "<td>%s</td>" %j
    result_string += "\n        </tr>\n"
result_string += """    </table>
</body>
</HTML>"""
display = open("table.html", 'w')
display.write(result_string)
display.close()

##for item in matches:
    ##print(item)
```

website.py

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask('flasksubs')
webcode = open('table.html').read()

@app.route('/')
def webprint():
    return webcode 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = '10.1.16.14', port = 82)
```

the code works, but i'm getting following list:

```
ISO LIST

Ubuntu10.1.iso
WindowsServer2016.iso
Ubuntu10.2.iso
```

Is it possible to use a 'simple' sort? so i would have:

```
ISO LIST

Ubuntu10.1.iso
Ubuntu10.2.iso
WindowsServer2016.iso
```

And even more perfect would be:

```
ISO LIST

UBUNTU:
Ubuntu10.1.iso
Ubuntu10.2.iso

WindowsServer:
WindowsServer2016.iso
```

So they appear in seperate tabs?

I already tried some things, but it doesn't work it.

Regards,
Ward

Comment: would help to show the content of `new_list`, but ultimately should be easy to solve with python's [**sorted()**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function. e.g. try `for i in sorted(new_list):` and/or `for j in sorted(i):`

Comment: my new_list is : `['Ubuntu.10.1.iso', 'Ubuntu.10.2.iso', 'Windows.Server.2016.iso']`, but my table.html is looking like this: `<HTML>
<body>
    <h1>ISO</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>U</td><td>b</td><td>u</td><td>n</td><td>t</td><td>u</td><td>.</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>.</td><td>2</td><td>.</td><td>i</td><td>s</td><td>o</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</HTML>` Why is this pls? @PJSantoro

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much just basic Python. If you need to construct HTML in your Python code (e.g. it's much better & more powerful to learn how to use Jinja2 to render templates!)

**Python Code:** *(changed the list so it wasn't sorted)*

```
new_list = ['Windows.Server.2016.iso', 'Ubuntu.10.1.iso', 'Ubuntu.10.2.iso']

table_rows = ['\t\t<tr><td>%s</td></tr>' % i for i in sorted(new_list)]

results_string = '\n'.join([
    '<html>',
    '<body>',
    '\t<h1>ISO LIST</h1>',
    '\t<table>',
    '\n'.join(table_rows),
    '\t</table>',
    '</body>',
    '</html>'
])
```

**print results_string:**

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>ISO LIST</h1>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Ubuntu.10.1.iso</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Ubuntu.10.2.iso</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Windows.Server.2016.iso</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I added `display = open("table.html", 'w')
display.write(results_string)
display.close()` to your code and table.html displays correctly now. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

The Flasky approach is to use [`render_template`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#template-rendering). Create an HTML file and use [Jinja syntax](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/) to display the data. Something like this:

### app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

def parse_key(match):
    for x, y in enumerate(match):
        if y.isdigit():
            return match[:x]

@app.route('/')
def index():
    data = {}
    matches = [
        'Ubuntu10.1.iso',
        'WindowsServer2016.iso',
        'Ubuntu10.2.iso'
    ]

    data = {parse_key(x): [y for y in matches if parse_key(y) == parse_key(x)] for x in matches}

    for key in data:
        data[key].sort()
    // check if the request is coming from JS.
    if request.is_xhr:
        return json.dumps(data)
    return render_template('ISOs.html', data=data)
```

### templates/ISOs.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>ISO List</h2>
    <div id="isoList">
        {% for key in data %}
        <h3>{{ key }}:</h3>
            <ul>
                {% for x in data[key] %}
                <li>{{ x }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
            <br>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Result:

### ISO List

#### WindowsServer:

- WindowsServer2016.iso

#### Ubuntu:

- Ubuntu10.1.iso
- Ubuntu10.2.iso

### EDIT:

Didn't realize this list had to be updated. Rather than reload the page, simply add some JavaScript to hit your endpoint on an [interval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp). Notice that I have changed both app.py and ISOs.html to work with the JS. You should probably read about this [method](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.is_xhr).

#### JavaScript

```
var $isoListDiv = $('#isoList'),
    checkISOList = function checkISOList() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/',
        type: 'GET'
    }).done(function(data) {
        try {
            JSON.parse(data);
        } catch (e) {
            // display error
            return false;
        }
        setISOList(data);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR) {
        // display error
    });
}, setISOList = function (data) {
    var isoList = "";
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
        isoList += "<h3>" + key + "</h3><ul>";
        for (var x = 0; x < data[key].length; x++) {
            isoList += "<li>" + data[key][x] + "</li>";
        }
        isoList += "</ul><br>";
    });
    $isoListDiv.html(isoList);
};
setInterval(checkISOList, 2000);
```

Comment: Fittler, thank your for your help. But on my synology i can't find a way to reload my flask page when table.html is changed. I think i need ajax/php for that and i don't know where to start.. I can display the page by going to http://ip/table.html for now.. Doing it flasky way would be the end goal.

Comment: I found a way to refresh the page `<script>
<!--
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
 setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}

window.onload = timedRefresh(5000);

//   -->
  </script>` So when my table.html is changed by a schedule task in Synology. My page will be refreshed in flask and the site can stay online(no need to stop start).

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize that was needed. I'll update.